# кастомный плеер не реагирует на плейлист

Tags: javascript, html

ставлю вот этот плеер http://playmju.ru/

в демке плейлист оформлен вида

```
var opera = Boolean(window["opera"]);
var ie = (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1) && !opera;

function mju_play_file(chars) {
    if (!chars.length) return false;
    var mc = ie ? window.mju : window.document.mju;
    mc.SetVariable("play_file",chars);
}

<a href="/" onclick="mju_play_file('to');return false;">track to</a><br>
<a href="/" onclick="mju_play_file('int');return false;">track int</a><br>
<a href="/" onclick="mju_play_file('zhe');return false;">track zhe</a><br>
```

по нажатию открывается файловый браузер

как исправить?

Comment: по нажатию куда?

Comment: на ссылку <a href="/"

Comment: а плейлист заполнили?

Comment: да, и вызываю
<li><img src="../../../../images/ot_images/icon_play.png"/><a href="#" onclick="mju_play_file("'.substr($file->getFilename(), 0, -1).'"); return false;">'.$file->getFilename().'</a></li>

Comment: причём mju_play_track(1) работает для 


function mju_play_track(num) {
      if (num <= 0) return false;
      var mc = ie ? window.mju : window.document.mju;
      mc.SetVariable("play_track",num);
     }

Comment: а вас не смущает что он пытается проиграть файл _to_ - он есть на вашем диске? :-)